# Quick search in dataframe

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, search, pymongo

We will be inserting data into mongodb. We are using pymongo.
We need to ensure that we insert a value into db only if the value is already not present in the db.
Since find() operation for every record to check for dup takes a long time, one suggestion was to bring entire values from db into list based on an identifier and search for the value in this list instead of doing find multiple times.
Here, the issue i am facing is if there are 1 million records for that identifier in db and i bring in the 1 million records into list. while processing 3k of my new records, i was checking for each record in 1 million which took around 9 minutes for the entire processing. I am assuming that this list can be replaced by dataframe for the faster search but someone can please help me achieve?

This is my code snippet to bring in the records into list first:

```
project_keys = {"_id":0}
for key in queryString:
            project_keys[key] = 1
curr_data_arr = list(audit_collection.find({"source_name":default_attributes['source_name']}, project_keys))
```

Processing of new records:

```
df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

    
    for row in df_dict:
        
        query_string={}
        
        for i in range(len(queryString)):
            if(queryString[i]=="source_name"):
                query_string[queryString[i]]=default_attributes["source_name"]
            else:
                query_string[queryString[i]]=row[queryString[i]]
                
      
        if(len(query_string)!=0):
            audit_data = next((sub for sub in curr_data_arr if (sub == query_string)), None)
            logger.info(f"Duplicate data check in list from mongo db, result is {audit_data}")
        else:
            audit_data = {}
            
        
        # do not insert/update if record found for audit data, log it and move to next record
        if(audit_data):
            duplicate_data_count += 1
            # logger.info(f"Duplicate record found for audit. Duplicate record being inserted: {row}")
            continue
        # Insert if no record found
        else:
            arr.append(row)
            new_data_count += 1

if(len(arr)>0):
        logger.info(f"Length of unique array is {len(arr)}")
        audit_collection.insert_many(arr)
```

So in above code snippet this will take ling processing time `audit_data = next((sub for sub in curr_data_arr if (sub == query_string))`. Example: db has 1 million records and currently i am inserting 3k records which took 9 minutes to check. If i remove that line without duplicate data check, data insertion takes place within 1 minute. How do i make this duplicate data check faster? Can i bring in the data in a dataframe instead and search in a dataframe instead of list? NOTE: Search would be based on primary key/queryString. would it become faster? Please provide code snippets

Comment: Couldn't you let the MongoDB server do all the work for you by using a [`bulk_write`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) with [`UpdateOne`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.UpdateOne) operations with the `upsert` option selected?  An index on your filtered fields may also be useful.

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Comment: @rickhg12hs -> insert_many did 10lakh insertion in 1 minute. Its pretty fast. I don't have a concern with inserting just checking for duplicate values already in db. Could you help with that?

Comment: @JamesZ 1 lakh = 1,00,000
sorry and hope this is clear now

Comment: Can this not be done faster using loading results from mongo into dataframe instead of list. Set index with queryString and use df.loc?

Comment: Would you show a few example documents?